# What is the number of cyclic graphs with $n$ vertices and how to enumerate them?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For example, let the vertices be labeled as $A,B,\dots$. Then,

- there is 1 circular graph of three vertices, with edges $\{(A,B), (B,C), (A,C)\}$, and
- there are 3 circular graphs of four vertices, with edges $\{(A,B), (B,C), (C,D), (A,D)\}$, $\{(A,C), (B,C), (B,D), (A,D)\}$, or $\{(A,B), (B,D), (C,D), (C,A)\}$.

How many circular undirected simple graphs $C_n$ are there in general with $n$ vertices?
Moreover, how can the sets of edges of such graphs be enumerated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ labelled cycles. This is because, starting from vertex $A$ you can list the other vertices round the cycle in $(n-1)!$ different ways (all possible orderings of $n-1$ things), but this counts every cycle twice, because you can go around the cycle in either direction.

Comment: Thank you very much! So a way to enumerate them would be, e.g.: (i) start from A, (ii) draw $v_1$ from $V\setminus \{A\}$ and set $e_1=(A,v_1)$, (iii) draw $e_2$ from $V\setminus \{A,v_1\}$ and set $e_2=(v_1,v_2)$ …. Then as long as the vertices are ordered in the edge tuples, the duplicates should be identical and easy to remove.

Comment: @teemu, yes, except I assume you mean "as long as vertices are unordered in the edge tuples". Alternatively, you can go through only keeping the ones where $v_1$ is earlier (alphabetically) than $v_{n-1}$; exactly one of each pair of duplicates satisfies this.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant mathematically. I was thinking a bit programmatically there.